# Cassandra 2.1 - missing system tables in system.schema_columnfamilies

Tags: cassandra

This query:

```
select columnfamily_name from system.schema_columnfamilies 
where keyspace_name='system'
```

has empty result in Cassandra 2.1, in 2.0 it returns table names:

```
IndexInfo
NodeIdInfo
batchlog
compaction_history
compactions_in_progress
hints
local
paxos
peer_events
peers
range_xfers
schema_columnfamilies
schema_columns
schema_keyspaces
schema_triggers
sstable_activity
```

Is there a way to list names of system tables in Cassandra 2.1?

Comment: I've just run that exact same query against my 2.1.2 installation and it returns the table names. Which version are you on and is this an upgrade?

Comment: It's a fresh installation on windows.

Answer (score 0):

this question is not correct. It is working on linux installation, it just does not work on my windows installation. So I am getting results on 2.0 and nothing on 2.1 - there must be something wrong with my installation.....

Comment: Have you looked in your logs to see if there are any errors during startup?